# Redis crashes instantly without error

Tags: redis

I've got redis installed on my VM, and I haven't used it in a while.  (Last I was using it, it did work, and now it doesn't.. nothing's changed in that time (about a month)).  Needless to say I'm deeply confused but I'll post as much info as I can.

`$ redis-server`

Server starts, but throws a warning about overcommit memory being set to 0. I'm on a VM, so I can't change this setting from 0 to 1 if I wanted, which I wouldn't want to anyway for my purposes.  I've written a custom `redis.config` file though, which I want it to use (and which I was using in the past), so starting it with the default config file doesn't do me much good.  Let's try this again.

```
$ redis-server redis.config
$
```

Nothing. Silence. No error message, just didn't start.

`$ nohup redis-server redis.config > nohup.out&`

I get a process ID, but then `$ ps` and I see the the process is listed as `stop` and shortly disappears. Again, no errors, and no output in nohup.out nor in the log file for redis.  Below is the redis.config I'm using (without the comments to keep it short)

```
daemonize yes
pidfile [my-user-account-path]/redis/redis.pid
port 0
bind 127.0.0.1
unixsocket [my-user-account-path]/tmp/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 770
timeout 10
tcp-keepalive 60
loglevel warning
logfile [my-user-account-path]/redis/logs/redis.log
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
rdbcompression no
rdbchecksum no
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir [my-user-account-path]/redis/db
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-priority 100
appendonly no
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128

# ADVANCED CONFIG is set to all default settings#
```

I'm sure it's probably something stupid, probably even a permissions thing somewhere (I've tried executing this as root, fyi), to no avail.  Anyone ever experience something similar with Redis?

Comment: Make sure that the pidfile does **not** exist before starting redis, though that should give you a hint in the log.

Comment: the pidfile did exist, but removing it the same thing still happens. (it does create a new pidfile though)

Comment: With the pid file gone, the redis log now says:

`[23272] 11 Apr 12:40:55.860 # Unable to set the max number of files limit to 10032 (Operation not permitted), setting the max clients configuration to 3984.
[23272] 11 Apr 12:40:55.861 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.10
[23272] 11 Apr 12:40:55.861 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.`

Comment: neither of these should cause the server to hangup though, at least, I don't think they should...

Comment: Actually the [FAQ](http://redis.io/topics/faq) (`CTRL+F` for *Background saving is failing with a fork() error under Linux even if I've a lot of free RAM!*) says that you might have some issues if `overcommit` is set to 0 .

Answer (score 1):

i have been experiencing redis crashes as well. just an fyi - the guy responsible for much of redis' development, Salvatore Sanfilippo, aka antirez, keeps an interesting blog that has some insight on redis crashes:

http://antirez.com/news/43